# How to install node + vue web program offline

Tags: node.js, vue.js, installation, centos

Hey Im looking for a good and solid solution for how to install node + vuejs full stack web program in offline. Our customer can not have any internet access so we have to install it in offline but cant imagine how to do. First idea was copy all the code including node modules and just paste it to the customer’s computer and run it. However I do bot believe this is gonna work.

Customer uses Centos as fas as I know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " However I do bot believe this is gonna work." Why not? Build your app for the targeted platform, copy all files over (incl. node: https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and run the app.

Comment: If you run `npm i` on cent-os and then copy-paste - it might work. But still - Vue CLI is required to run, and it needs to be installed via npm, and it requires the internet.

Comment: @vovchisko so, you're saying I can't run vue-cli project even I copied and pasted all code, packages, and  node_modules, right? well... that's gonna be a huge problem then...

Comment: @ChaehwaRyu you possibly can build nix image with all things you need, and install it on a client's machine. As it will include flash-drive delivery with installation - might be an option to simply share wifi hotspot with a mobile phone once to run `npm i`.

Comment: @vovchisko Many thanks for the suggestion. However the machine is not possbiel to share any wifi as well. It's government building. Nothing is accepted. Though, I will write down your idea and try for other solutions when it comes! :)

Comment: @ChaehwaRyu Also if you need it just to show - you can try to make Electron app - https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who's looking for a 'how to' steps for offline centOS install.

Preparation

1. a laptop or Computer can access to the internet.
2. Install VM or whatever you want to use to set the whole project in CentOS
3. Install CentOS7 in your VM and connect to the internet.

   **!! Important!!**
   You MUST Follow your customer's centOS install options. There are many options you can select when you install your centOS. When you install your project in offline, you have to have all the packages(or dependencies) depends on OS installed options. If your customer installed CentOS as full development package, then you don't have to have additional dependencies. if not, you need a lot.
4. download all the packages you need as CentOS version. In my case, my web is based on `'Nodejs + Express', 'Vuejs + AntDesign', pm2, nginx` so I have donwnloaded nodejs, nginx, and pm2. Others are gonna work without any problems once you've installed Nodejs. If you need some additional packages or dependencies(it will be written in the terminal message during installation process of node or others) then write down all the packages and install them.
5. Set your project in CentOS and test if it works(build the project if it's needed). If it does not work, check the path, dependencies, or anything else might be related(DO NOT FORGET LINUX AUTHORITY!!).
6. If everything works, then get all the installation file(.rpm) you've installed.
7. install another CentOS in VM as **OFFLINE**
8. install in offline CentOS .rpm installation files you get from online CentOS above.(no. 6) (DO Exactly same installation but this time, with only the files. not from the online repositories)
9. Test
10. If it's not working, check the path, root or user's authority in CentOS.

---

**About PM2.**

1. As PM2 is for the process management, **you have to install it globally**. However, sometimes(I tested 2 times in exactly same set environments. First try did work but second try didn't work. Couldn't find why. I've tested 4.3 and it works every time so I suggest you to get the pm2 version under 4.5) pm2 v.4.5 or up does not support offline installation with npm so All you have to do in online centos:
   `npm pack pm2`(whatever you've set the name when you installed pm2 in online centos, if you didn't change the package name then `npm pack pm2` will work, command path doesn't matter. pm2 is installed globally so when you run `npm pack pm2` anywhere it will take global installed `pm2` whatsoever) This will pack all the dependencies to install pm2 in offline. Take this packed file(.tgz) and install this in offline.
2. Test
3. If it's not working and you couldn't find the reason why, leave a comment or answers down below. I will try to help as much as I can.(I'm Korean and live in Korea. Please be aware of time difference)